# Reading data from an IRT executable

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

So i want to read and send data from a module (MinIMU 9 v5) i installed [a library](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/minimu9-ahrs) that reads the data from a sensor throught I2C. I just want to read a single line of data and then send it, and my question is how to achieve that?
Output from this file (minimu9-ahrs) looks like that:

```
  -1318   -3106   -1801     1896    1219    3679        5      18       3
  -1318   -3106   -1801     1898    1200    3681        0      24      -1
  -1318   -3106   -1801     1899    1200    3688       15      17       2
  -1309   -3105   -1799     1874    1201    3671       17      20      -1
  -1309   -3105   -1799     1898    1214    3663       11      15      -2
```

It's updated in real time and i dont know how to extract just a single line from this (preferably using python). Its an executable with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed my problem by editing the library to make it write data to file data instead of printing it. (the exact file i edited was *minimu9-ahrs.cpp* in function *void stream_raw_values(imu & imu)*)